How to Respond to File Selections in a Blender Add-on Using the File Browser?
I'm developing a Blender add-on that uses the built-in file browser. I want to update the property panel with information related to the selected files. For example, when a file is selected, I want to display the number of lines in the file on the property panel.
How can I make my add-on respond to file selections and unselections in the file browser so I can update the file info on the property panel?
